# Does "…with vaccine misinformation now a key concern" mean "…and vaccine misinformation is now a major concern"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

> Misinformation continually threatens efforts to control the COVID-19 pandemic, with vaccine misinformation now a key concern.

I am confused about the usage of "with". When I translate the sentence above with google translate, it means the following in my native language:

> Misinformation continually threatens efforts to control the COVID-19 pandemic, and vaccine misinformation is now a major concern.

My question is that do the two sentences have the same meaning? If they are same how "with" became "and" and is there a omitting "is" between "misinformation" and "now"? If there is, how is this possible?

Lastly I also didn't understand the function of "with" in the sentence below. Where does "with" belong?

Could you write this sentence more clearly please

> News items were more likely to be remembered when they aligned with participants' pre-existing vaccine beliefs, with stronger effects for pro-vaccine information.

Comment: The with sentence means the same thing as the rewrite. Please, forget google translate. It's terrible. Anglo journalism uses the with preposition in that way.

Comment: This is a "journalese" style of English.

Comment: I see nothing "wrong" with the example. It's not specifically journalese, just normal English. Perhaps some pedants might prefer *...with vaccine misinformation now **being** a key concern,* but imho it's fine as it is.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If I were overseeing a Phd, I'd mark in red.

Comment: @Lambie: Imho that just makes you a misguided pedant. I might look for some upmarket texts featuring this construction, but what's the point?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Really? Better writing in a Phd is misguided and pedantic? Hm. "now that vaccine information is a key concern".  In this case.

Comment: You have your own (peculiar) ideas about what constitutes "better writing". In any case, *"now that vaccine information is a key concern"* doesn't mean *exactly* the same as the actual text cited by OP (whereas if you include ***being*** as per my comment, this doesn't change the meaning *at all*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Never has anyone called my ideas about writing peculiar. I think you might examine that very large chip weighing down your shoulder in matters of elegant writing. Just can't bear to hear that one thing might be better than another, even if only aesthetically speaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This use of the word ***with*** is very similar to ***what with*** (which *could* be used in OP's example; in practice it makes little if any difference to the *meaning*). Except that ***what with*** is "conversational / colloquial", whereas the version as cited is perfectly acceptable even in more formal contexts.

> **what with** [<sub>Collins Dictionary</sub>](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/what-with)
> used to talk about the reasons for a particular situation, especially a bad or difficult situation
> *I'm very tired, what with travelling all day yesterday and having a disturbed night.*

In OP's cited context, *[what] **with*** implies that the *preceding* clause refers to a "bad" situation, for which the *following* clause provides emphasis and gives a specific additional example.

---

In OP's example, the secondary clause ***with** vaccine misinformation now [**being**] a key concern* is semantically almost identical to the standalone sentence *Vaccine misinformation **is** now a key concern*. All the word ***with*** does is explicitly alert us that the secondary assertion is *very closely connected to the preceding assertion* (as does the word ***and*** in OP's suggested alternative).

---

TL;DR: So far as I'm concerned, OP's suggested rephrasing means *exactly* the same as the original. As can be seen from comments, at least *some* people might think the original ***with*** version is stylistically weak or otherwise inappropriate. I doubt anyone would say that about OP's alternative - but that's irrelevant to me because I have no problem with the original anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Merriam-Webster has a long list of uses of [with](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/with), including 7b "used as a function word to indicate an attendant fact or circumstance". While "and" can be used to yank together any two statements regardless of their connection, "which" indicates the nature of the connection more specifically: it's weaker than "because" but more specific than "meanwhile".

You could substitute "Misinformation continually threatens efforts to control the COVID-19 pandemic, in a world where vaccine misinformation is now a key concern." Grammatically this is slightly different, with a subordinate clause rather than a prepositional phrase, but the meaning is similar. (It is the nature of language that you can't usually replace one word with another that has exactly the same meaning and syntax.)